# How to add multiple views to the detail fragment without using xml?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

In an Activity I have two fragments A and B. A is a ListFragment and B extends Fragment. I was successful in establishing a communication between the two. When you select an Item in Fragment A the Fragment B is supposed to show a TextView, and a couple of button. So I put the views in a ViewGroup and tried to pass it to Fragment B. When debugged, it executed the right lines, but the views never appear in Fragment B. I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Now, given that I am not allowed to use xml to create views, how can I accomplish this?

All the examples, and questions in stackoverflow are either about just one view or views that have been created with xml. I dont know how inflater would be of any help to me.

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreateView function of your Fragment B , you can create a view group at run time that can be returned .

Answer (score 0):

@umesh I tried, it didn't work for me. However, after hours of browsing on the web I learnt that I can use LinearLayout. add the views to it and return the layout. That worked! Thanks though.